# How to indicate that a Class object should represent a subtype of an interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have the following enum:

```
public enum NotifierTypes {
    EMAIL(EmailNotifier.class);
    SMS(SmsNotifier.class)

    private final Class internalValue;

    NotifierTypes(Class internalValue) {
        this.internalValue = internalValue;
    }

    public Class getNotifierClass() {
        return internalValue;
    }
}

public interface INotifier {...}
public class EmailNotifier implements INotifier {...}
```

I want the arguments provided to the constructor to represent types that implement an interface, say `INotifier`. How can I do that?

Comment: Which values? The enum constants? The constructor arguments?

Comment: All values. The enum constants that are provided by the constructor arguments.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The enum constants are `EMAIL` and `SMS`. The constructor arguments are `SmsNotifier.class` and `EmailNotifier.class`. Do you want your type `NotifierTypes` (and therefore its instances, the enum constants) to implement the `INotifier` interface or do you want the constructor arguments to represent types that are subtypes of `INotifier`.

Comment: Not the `NotifierTypes`, but the values behind this enum constants.

Comment: You're just confusing this further. `NotifierTypes` is an enum type, a special type of class. Classes can implement interfaces. `EMAIL` and `SMS` are references to two different instances of type `NotifierTypes`. Do you want `NotifierTypes` to implement `INotifier`?

Comment: No, I want the internal values to do so. Please edit the question to make it clear, if it is now clear for you. If not, the answer below does the job. So you can fix the text as needed. This will help me more actually. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121948/discussion-between-gabriel-petrovay-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generic bound:

```
private final Class<? extends INotifier> internalName;

NotifierTypes(Class<? extends INotifier> internalName){ /* ... */ }

public Class<? extends INotifier> getIntName(){ /* ... */ }
```